# blank page between table of contents and list of figures

Tags: chapters

How I can add a blank page between table of contents and list of figures ?  List of figures should begin in the right page

Comment: You are perhaps interested in the `twopage` document class option? That is, `\documentclass[twoside]{report}`?

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Answer (score 2):

If you want that, you can use this:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{report}
```

- `twoside`: Sets different margins (and some other stuff) in odd and even pages.
- `openright`: Chapters open on the right page.

You should probably want to use this package too:

```
\usepackage{emptypage}
```

This package makes the blank page really blank, without page number and that stuff.